# collect min max and sum of 3 different column in 1 tuple based on another column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I had following table

```
 __________________________________________________________
|             |              |             |      |       |
|OpeningAmount|PeriodicAmount|ClosingAmount|Years | Month |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 10000       |  100         | 9900        | 2014 | 1     |
| 99000       |  100         | 9800        | 2014 | 2     |
| 98000       |  100         | 9700        | 2014 | 3     |
| 97000       |  100         | 9600        | 2014 | 4     |
| 10000       |  100         | 9900        | 2015 | 1     |
| 99000       |  100         | 9800        | 2015 | 2     |
| 98000       |  100         | 9700        | 2015 | 3     |
| 97000       |  100         | 9600        | 2015 | 4     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need following table

```
 ____(MAX)_______(SUM)___________(MIN)_____________
|             |              |             |      |
|OpeningAmount|PeriodicAmount|ClosingAmount|Years |
---------------------------------------------------
| 10000       |  400         | 9600        | 2014 |
| 10000       |  400         | 9600        | 2015 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

please help me to process this in Mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(OpeningAmount),sum(PeriodicAmount),min(ClosingAmount),Years 
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE group by Years;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(OpeningAmount),
SUM(PeriodicAmount),
MIN(ClosingAmount),
Years
from MyTable
GROUP BY 
Years
```